# Remove duplicates from database output

Tags: bash, awk, sed, postgresql

Assume you have three tables in a database: name, email and phone. If you join these tables you may get following output:

```
Alice Miller, alice@it.com, 12345
Alice Miller, am@uni.edu, 12345
Alice Miller, alice@it.com, 56789
Alice Miller, am@uni.edu, 56789
```

How do I format this output to get rid of redundant information. I want it like

```
Alice Miller, alice@it com, 12345
, am@uni.edu, 56789
```

So, only once the name and then all email in one column and all phone numbers in the third column.

I don't expect a SQL-statement, but maybe some hints how to format with sed or awk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not do it [with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43870/2344631)?

Comment: Ok, well, then also with SQL.